# Chat application in Swift ios9

Tags: swift, mongodb, ios9, chat, instant-messaging

I would like to implement messaging in my app.
Every user will have an inbox and could be able to send messages to another user.

I do not want to use Parse or Firebase because I already have a MongoDB and a backend API to manage users. I also use FacebookLogin/Logout.

Are you aware of a good SDK to help me realizing this feature? Or a tutorial to start somewhere?

Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: I tried nothing for the moment. Every API I found with Google research works with Parse or use their own DB (Firebase for example). Every tutorial I found was not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally did in a location based chat app using push notifications and saving the messages sent and received on a database.

When a user sends a message you simultaneously send a push notification to the user and save it on your database. When the user checks their inbox view it will load the data saved on the inbox table. 
Using this approach you can choose which ever database and push notification provider you prefer.

Another option is using websockets for real time communication.

Comment: I never used push notifications for the moment, but it is a good opportunity to start! Thank you for the advice

Comment: You're welcome! Once you figure the push notifications you'll see its fairly easy to implement. I recommend this server https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushserver for push notifications.

Comment: That is a place to start for this feature, everything I asked for here. Thank you!